# Is it okay to use map as a for loop without returning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use map everywhere in my project, even when i don't want to return anything, i simply use `{}` instead of `()` and don't return anything and simply use it like a `for loop`, is this okay? and if it is, what about not using any key ?, because i sometimes don't really work with elements inside the map, i don't even need to (or know how) to use key for it!
**Here is an example which i copied from my code:**

```
rawElementList.map(element => {
    if (element.validation !== undefined) {                 
        if (JavascriptUtils.hasOwnProperty(element.validation, 'isRequired')) {
            const isRequired = element.validation.isRequired;

            if (isRequired !== undefined) {
                delete element.validation.isRequired;
                required.push(String(element.id))
            }
        }

        validationJsonList.properties[element.id] = element.validation;
    }
})
```

Comment: But why ? why not `forEach` ? use `forEach` for such cases

Comment: @CodeManiac I don't know, it was comfy! and since i was novice and i didn't know much about java script, i simply used what i knew, specially because map would iterate over each element

Comment: You should use `forEach` which is specifically designed for such cases !!! [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not appropriate. You will greatly confuse any other readers of your code when you use a method specifically designed to create an array, but don't *actually* create a meaningful array. Use `forEach` instead - it's the most appropriate array method for just side-effects:

```
rawElementList.forEach(element => {
    if (element.validation !== undefined) {                 
        if (JavascriptUtils.hasOwnProperty(element.validation, 'isRequired')) {
            const isRequired = element.validation.isRequired;

            if (isRequired !== undefined) {
                delete element.validation.isRequired;
                required.push(String(element.id))
            }
        }

        validationJsonList.properties[element.id] = element.validation;
    }
})
```

Comment: Just curios, what are the side effects of what i did ?, is it slower?, will it create a bug ? , or simply confuses other coders?

Comment: You have 3 side effects in that code: the last 3 lines with content in them. `delete element.validation.isRequired;`, `delete element.validation.isRequired;`, and `validationJsonList.properties[element.id] = element.validation;`. Side effects often aren't a *bad* thing - they're contrasted with pure(r) functions, which only create and return new things (like `.map` is for).

Comment: It is slower because you create an array during map, if you do it correctly, you don't create bugs by using map vs forEach, but it is easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i refactored all the codes i had and used `forEach` anywhere i didn't return anything, i miss the days where there was only a single ` For loop` :d